# Flutter: How to show FCM push notification outside the app when the app is not open

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to show notifications outside my app like the screenshot that I attached? I know I see this with WhatsApp and some other apps. I have an FCM that works well, it show on the notification bar of the device but I want the notification to take fullscreen of the device while I am on another app or home screen of my device like my attached image, below is what my firebase looks like in flutter.

[image]

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        _showItemDialog(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
    );
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you can't do this in Android but I know you can't on iOS. Overall...the FCM architecture was built to use the notification bar. Doing full view notifications outside of your app is a pretty intrusive experience and I wouldn't recommend it.